# how to extract text in an grayscale image that has other features like scratches in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to remove just the text area of an image as close as possible because I want to extract scratches on a surface. The issue here is that the text is lasered on a case and it is possible that the case has scratches on its surface which I want to detect. Here are some examples (Left is the mask image created through thresholding, the middle image is the one where I removed the text with inpainting and the right one is the original image):

[image]

In this picture we see a scratch on the left-bottom and two scratches in the area where the text is. I threshold the image so I can get a mask and then use the `inpaint` method. That works fine but I just want to do the inpainting for the text, not the scratches.

This is the method where I do the inpainting:

```
    def MaskOutMarking(self, img):
    # Binary threshold image
    mask = cv2.threshold(img, 150, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

    # Remove small noise
    inp_mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5, 5)))

    cv2.imshow('Mask', mask)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

    # Dilate mask
    inp_mask = cv2.dilate(inp_mask,
                          cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (15, 15)))

    # Inpaint
    dst = cv2.inpaint(img, inp_mask, 15, cv2.INPAINT_NS)

    #cv2.imshow('Mask', inp_mask)
    #cv2.waitKey(0)

    return dst
```

I thought of maybe extracting the contours and then filter the scratches but I dont know how I should remove the non-text features with it. Maybe get the x biggest contours? But what do I do when there are bigger scratches or something. I am a little bit stumped....

Here is an original image:

[image]

Comment: filter by aspect ratio and area

Comment: can you provide original image?

Comment: I added the original image

Comment: Threshold the image. Then find contours. Then filter the contours on area and perhaps other shape metrics and draw filled black polygons over the image where you want to remove objects